# Suggestions/Advice about conflicts on jQuery and Prototype in cakePHp?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, cakephp-1.2

I use the prototype library that makes up my ajax call in cakephp..

I also have jquery codes in some part of my application..

In jQuery part (in the view), i use the $.noConflict to make make sure that everything will work,
some work but some are not working and i dont know why...

Any advice/suggestions on how i can avoid these?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script src="prototype.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery.js"></script>
     <script>
       var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
       ...
```

now instead of $(etc...
use $j(etc....

Answer (score 0):

For a similar situation in Grails, the problem is solved by using jQuery instead of $.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $.noConflict();
       jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
       });
       // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
     </script>
```

we can use $ if we wish without fear of conflicts.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would consider [migrating to CakePHP 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3), as the new [JS helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1592/Js) has full jQuery support, so you wouldn't need to include 2 separate javascript libraries, which is going to always cause you headaches down the line when you use plugins and code samples, as well as slowing down page load times.